# Mongoose populate nested question. I am still only getting objectId

Tags: mongoose

[I just have a question about populating nested. I based the syntax on stackoverflow. no errors but productId is still showing up as the ObjectId instead of filling it with product model.  Is there something wrong with the syntax? Clicking this link goes to a photo of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z5Zn.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
User.find({})
  .populate({
    path: 'orderHistory',
    populate: {
      path: 'products',
      populate: {
        path: 'productId'
      }
    }
  })
```

The above works. I wasn't nesting the populate correctly.